# Calculate GPS elevation angle (Python)

Tags: python, gps, latitude-longitude, mathematics

I have two GPS points (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude) the distance between the two points is a maximum of 50 kilometers.  How can I calculate the elevation angle?  (I want to implement the whole thing in Python)

Comment: This might help: https://groups.google.com/g/cesium-dev/c/erIWDi1Y54g?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the coordinates from lat/long to a datum that uses meters such as UTM, and also make sure your elevation values are in meters, then you just need to use the Pythagorean theorem to find the Euclidean distance between the two points based on x and y, then find the angle from horizontal using the inverse tangent of the elevation difference divided by the euclidean distance.

[image]